# SQL Server Integrated Authentication on Weblogic Server

Tags: sql-server, weblogic, windows-authentication, weblogic-10.x

I'm developing a web application that accesses data on MS SQL Server 2012. My company's production environment already has connections to the database set up using SQL Server Authentication. My Active Directory account does not include SQL Server authentication, and we use Integrated Authentication when we are developing on our local machines. I am testing my application by deploying it to a local instance of Weblogic 10.3.4.

I am receiving this exception when attempting to create the connection pool on the Administration Console:

```
<Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Console encountered the following error com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
```

I've added sqljdbc_auth.dll to the classpath on the server, and added:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\programdata\Oracle\WebLogicServer\10.3.4\user_projects\domains\JDEV\lib
```

to my server start arguments in the Environment -> Server Start tab on the management console, but there is still something wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried something like http://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/how-to-add-third-party-jdbc-drivers-on-weblogic-64/ to put the driver on your classpath? The example is for Linux but the files are more or less the same

Comment: @DisplayNameisMissing Thanks for your comment. I believe this article is trying to explain the absence of the driver in general, my problem here was that integrated authentication was not working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I believe that I did not have the sqljdbc_auth.dll in the correct location. It belongs in:

```
%path%\WebLogicServer\10.3.4\wlserver_10.3\server\native\win\x64
```

Once I put this file in the correct location, the configuration worked right away.

It is also important to note that the version number on these files is **very** important. Make sure that your sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc_auth.dll versions are **exactly** the same, otherwise the container will blow up and you'll end up being frustrated like me.